# PATCH request don't work in ODATA with DataServiceContext and If-Match

Tags: odata, patch, conditional-operator, etag

The ODATA Version is 4 and the ODATA Client Version is 7.13.00.

I try to send a conditional PATCH request using If-Match header using the OData Client Context and a DataServiceCollection and SaveChanges() method as shown in the code below. In the If-Match header, the value is an old ETag (corresponding to MyProperty = 50), and I expect the PATCH request to throw an exception, as the entity has been updated, so it should fail, but instead, the update the of  MyProperty property is done correctly.

```
  var retrievedEntity = clients.MyEntity.ByKey("1000").GetValue();
  retrievedEntity.MyProperty = 80;
  clients.UpdateObject(QueryBC6TransferOrder);
  DataServiceResponse response = clients.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.None);
```

I tried another solution using the clients.Execute method as show below, but with no luck because it throws the exception: "The HttpMethod must be GET, POST or DELETE. (Parameter 'httpMethod')"

```
clients.Execute(clients.BC6_Transfer_OrderTransferLines.RequestUri, "PATCH", new BodyOperationParameter("QtyToReceive", -90) as OperationParameter);
```

Please note that we added the If-Match header for both solutions using the following code with uses the BuildingRequest event of the client where we specify the PATCH method to be used during the SaveChanges call:

```
private static void Context_BuildingRequest(object sender,Microsoft.OData.Client.BuildingRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Headers.ContainsKey("If-Match"))
            {
                e.Headers.Add("If-Match", "*");
            }
            else
            {
                e.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
                e.Method = "PATCH";
            }
        }
```

We assume either the request is not using the PATCH method or the If-Match header is not taken into account. Can someone help me to find a solution or understand what is wrong in the code. I followed the Microsoft documentation with no luck and the following tutorial:, but with POSTMAN, the If-Match header is taken into account and the entity is not updated if the ETag changed before the PATCH method. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/tutorial-sample-client-property-tracking-for-patch/

Thank